# css Flexbox: switch card text axis on shrink

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have a Card i.e. a component with an image and an area for text, which I want to display horizontally ( img-area -> text-area ) on larger screens, and vertically (text-area under img-area) on smaller screens.

If I shrink the page dimensions, I can get the text area to wrap to the new line, but there is a point where the text area is wider than the image, causing an unwanted effect. I want the text area to jump under the image immediately.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Portfolio.js render

```
            <div className="property">
                <div className="property-img">
                    <img src="/brick_wall.jpg" />
                </div>                       
                <div className="property-text">
                    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Portfolio.css

```
.property {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px #333;
  margin: 20px;
}

.property-img {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 500px;
}

.property-img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;

  align-self: flex-start;
  flex-grow: 2;
  flex-shrink: 2;

}


.property-text{
    background: white;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    flex-basis: 480px;
    flex-grow: 2;
    flex-shrink: 2;
}
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly, you want to move from screen 1 to screen 3?

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov that's right

Comment: Check my answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use fixed width:50% to the left and right column instead of flexbox stretch and then make it 100% with media query when it's needed to be one under the other. Besides, you can load image in the left column by using background-image property instead of image tag.